# Who licenses Stack Exchange content to end users?

Tags: licensing, creative-commons

If I take content that's posted on Stack Exchange (or, more generically, from a site that publishes user content based on a CC BY-SA license) and re-use it elsewhere, who is my license from? Is it the author themselves, or is it from Stack Exchange (from the publishing site)?

Relatedly, who has the authority to request that attribution be removed? CC BY-SA provides for the licensor to request attribution be removed, but who has to make that request in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### It’s spelled out [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing)

Stack Exchange content and the compilation is licensed to you by Stack Exchange. Subscriber content is licences to you by the subscriber since the licence they grant allows subsequent relicensing.